# Split a list into smaller lists where each smaller list is subsequently smaller by using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, list-comprehension

I have a list that I would like to split into a list of lists, such that each list in the new list is one element smaller.

For example:

```
exampleList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

newList = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
       [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
       [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
       [4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
       [5,6,7,8,9,10],
       [6,7,8,9,10],
       [7,8,9,10],
       [8,9,10],
       [9,10]]
```

Is there an easy way to do this via list comprehension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use slicing and a list comprehension.

```
>>> [exampleList[i:] for i in range(len(exampleList) - 1)] 
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [7, 8, 9, 10], [8, 9, 10], [9, 10]]
```

`exampleList[i:]` will take all elements from the current index `i` to the end. If you want to include `[10]` in the result, omit the `- 1` from the call to `len`.

Answer (score 0):

Go with @timgeb solution , alternate version could be

```
res = [lst[i:] for i, _ in enumerate(lst[:-1])]
```

Other possibility using `map`

```
res = list(map(lambda x: lst[x-1:], lst[:-1]))
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [7, 8, 9, 10], [8, 9, 10], [9, 10]]
```